# How to subscribe and receive data from server-to-user channel with pusher-js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, vercel, pusher, pusher-js

I host my application with next.js on Vercel. To provide real-time messages to the user in the app, I would like to implement Pusher. Every user should be reachable via a channel, of course private and secure.

Based on the logs, everything seems to be working, however, I can't manage to subscribe to the channel and get the message of the event. I have tested several possibilities, however, I have not succeeded so far.

**Server-side: /pusher/user-auth/index.ts**

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const pusherService = container.resolve(PusherService);
    const manageToken = container.resolve(ManageToken);
    const loggingService = container.resolve(LoggingService);

    loggingService.info('PUSHER /api/pusher/user-auth - Authenticate user');

    const socketId = req.body.socket_id as string;
    const token = req.headers['x-csrf-token'] as string;

    const currentUser = await manageToken.verifyUserToken(token);

    const authResponse = await pusherService.authenticateUser(socketId, {
        id: currentUser.id,
        user_info: {
            lastName: currentUser.lastName,
            firstName: currentUser.firstName,
            email: currentUser.email,
        },
    });

    res.status(200).json(authResponse);
    return;
}
```

**Server-side: /pusher/auth/index.ts**

```
export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    const pusherService = container.resolve(PusherService);
    const loggingService = container.resolve(LoggingService);

    loggingService.info('PUSHER /api/pusher/auth - Authorize channel.');

    const socketId = req.body.socket_id as string;
    const channel = req.body.channel_name;
    const authResponse = pusherService.authorizeChannel(socketId, channel);
    res.status(200).json(authResponse);
    return;
}
```

**Server-side: /pusher-service.ts**

```
public async sendToUser(userId: string, event: string, data: any) {
    this.loggingService.info('Send event to user via Pusher.');
    try {
        return this.pusher.sendToUser(userId, 'generated', {message: 'hi'});
    } catch (e) {
        this.loggingService.error(e);
    }
}
```

**Client-side**

```
export const subscribe = async (token) => {
  log.info("Subscribe pusher channel.");

  Pusher.logToConsole = true;
  const pusher = new Pusher(process.env.REACT_APP_PUSHER_KEY, {
    cluster: "eu",
    channelAuthorization: {
      endpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_BLOOO_API_URL + "/pusher/auth"
    },
    userAuthentication: {
      endpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_BLOOO_API_URL + "/pusher/user-auth",
      headers: {
        "X-CSRF-Token": "Bearer " + token
      }
    }
  });

  pusher.signin();

  // SUBSCRIBE 

  // e.g. does not work
  // const channel = pusher.subscribe("#server-to-user-444") 
  // channel.bind("generated", (data) => {
  //   console.log(data);
  // });
};
```

**Client-side: Logs**

```
Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-eu.pusher.com:443/app/xxx?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.1.0&flash=false"}]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 123.123"]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:signin","data":{"auth":"123:123","user_data":"{\"id\":\"444\",\"user_info\":{\"lastName\":\"NAME\",\"firstName\":\"NAME\",\"email\":\"MAIL\"}}"}}]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher:signin_success","data":{"user_data":"{\"id\":\"444\",\"user_info\":{\"lastName\":\"NAME\",\"firstName\":\"NAME\",\"email\":\"MAIL\"}}"}}]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"#server-to-user-444"}}]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"#server-to-user-444","data":{}}]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on #server-to-user-444 for pusher:subscription_succeeded"]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"generated","channel":"#server-to-user-444","data":{"message":"hi"}}]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on user for generated"]
logger.ts:19 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on #server-to-user-444 for generated"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to bind to the user and not to the channel.

```
pusher.user.bind(eventName, callback);
```

https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events/#binding-on-the-user-object